# Прошу проверить пунктуацию

Tags: пунктуация

Вопросы типа: "Разве математика способна иметь цель?" или более обыденные "как математика вообще помогает миру?" — это косвенные вопросы, и они самые несомненно приветствуются.

Прошу не обращать внимания на контекст. Интересует корректное использование всех знаков; особенно смущают кавычки, поскольку обычно я их никогда не использую в письме, кроме, разве что, прямой речи.

Answer (score 1):

> Вопросы типа "Разве математика способна иметь цель?" или более обыденные "**К**ак
>   математика вообще помогает миру?" -- это косвенные вопросы, и они
>   (?)*самые* несомненно приветствуются.

Двоеточие не нужно (чего ради?).
Заглавная во втором вопросе (интересно, почему у вас только в первом)?
В конце что-то с грамматикой. Или со стилистикой - но тогда что-то поистине ужасное. Зачем здесь слово "самые"?
Что за проблема с кавычками - не понимаю. Они тут нужны и абсолютно понятны.

Смысл не доходит. Почему вопросы "косвенные" и почему они приветствуются - да еще "несомненно"? В зависимости от смысла можно будет уточнить остальные знаки.

(+)
По разговорам приходим к следующему.

***Вопросы типа "Разве математика способна иметь цель?" или более обыденные "Как математика вообще помогает миру?" -- это (?)косвенные вопросы, и они, несомненно, приветствуются.***

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Это вырванная из контекста часть моего диалога с товарищем -- особо не вникайте. Забыл подправить заглавную букву во вторых кавычках... А употребление слова "самые" -- это у меня что-то типа вредной привычки после "злоупотребления" философией. :)

Comment: @PersonaNonGrata во-первых, "диалоги" зачастую вообще невозожно оформить "по науке". Так что тут и вопрос так ставить не надо.  Во-вторых, что такое у вас "косвенные вопросы"? Мне как-то совершенно не нравится подход Sibylla, но если за этим "косвенные" ничего не стоит глубокого, то в одном она права - "несомненно" надо обособлять. Я поправил ответ.

Comment: это элементарный разбор ошибок, особо оформлять здесь что-то "по науке" я и не собирался. Косвенные вопросы, это как раз таки то, о чем я и говорил: "Не обращайте внимания на контекст". К своему стыду, признаю, что забыл обособить "несомненно"... Спасибо за исправления!

Comment: *оформлять здесь что-то "по науке" я и не собирался* - зачем тогда вообще этот вопрос? "По науке" - это в соответствии с правописанием. Разговорная речь (устная в первую очередь) не всегда в них укладывается, поскольку не соблюдается грамматика. Я заподозрил у вас именно такой случай - с нарушением грамматики. А если вы предлагаете вообще на смысл вниания не обращать, так это вообще не укладывается в голове.

Answer (score 0):

**Вопросы типа "Р(р)разве математика способна иметь цель?" или более обыденные "К(к)ак математика вообще помогает миру?" ― это косвенные вопросы, и они, несомненно, приветствуются.**

Прямая речь выступает в роли несогласованного определения к однородным членам (вопросы типа или более обыденные вопросы), связанным союзом ИЛИ, минимальное выделение прямой речи (без двоеточия и допускается строчная буква). Двоеточие нельзя использовать, так как  выражение "вопросы типа" относится только к первому вопросу.

**Примеры различных способов оформления подобных высказываний**

(1) Жители переулка неоднократно обращались в местную СЭС, но оттуда поступали **ответы типа**: «Во время наших рейдов факта торговли комбикормами обнаружено не было» **или** «Мы не можем подтвердить наличие огромного количества крыс в вашем переулке».  (Здесь двоеточие после обобщающего слова, прямая речь в виде однородных членов).

(2) Уже за неделю до Первомая стал получать от некоторых своих партнеров **ответы типа** «звоните после праздников» (минимальное выделение прямой речи).

(3) Почему не откликнулись ― мы так и не поняли, в приемных того и другого нам дали невразумительные **ответы типа**: ваше письмо с вопросами передано, но результата мы не знаем (дословное высказывание оформлено как БСП, без кавычек).

(4)Когда уходят последние объяснения, на первые уже приходят **ответы типа**: «Вот, блин!" (классическое оформление прямой речи с сохранением соответствующей интонации).

(5) **Ответы типа**: «Не знаю, мы выясним и доложим» ― не принимались (прямая речь внутри слов автора).

Comment: 1. Вопросы в кавычках - с заглавной. Это самстоятельные предложения. 2. Убрали без согласования с автором "они самые" - вы уверены, что не исказили суть? 3. Не выяснили, почему вопросы названы "косвенными", если за этим скрывается какой-то смысл, пунктуация может быть другой (гипотетически, но вполне вероятно). Но скорее всего автор назвал косвенными вопросы ***риторические***. Если уж править, то начиная с этого. 4.  Зачем столько противоречивых примеров, из которых не видна система?

Comment: Кстати Ваш (4) - весьма сомнительная пунктуация. Если "типа" то прямая речь вчисто виде исключается, двоеточие невозможно. "Типа" само играет роль двоеточия, встраивая перечисляемый ряд в предложения в роли самостоятельных членов.

Comment: 1. Употребление СТРОЧНОЙ буквы возможно: «Хочешь?», «давай ты» звучало в моих ушах и производило какое-то опьянение; я ничего и никого не видел, кроме Сонечки (Л. Т.); От его приветливого «я вас ждал» она повеселела (Б. П.) .  "Противоречивые примеры" говорят о том, что при цитировании возможны РАЗЛИЧНЫЕ СПОСОБЫ оформления, которые автор выбирает в зависимости  от структуры и стиля предложения. К примеру, использование классического оформления  прямой речи  для коротких фраз позволяет сделать паузу  и выразить  восклицание, вопрос, что невозможно при упрощенном оформлении.